# .getTextContent returns text from child elements too

Tags: java, xml, string, get, element

I'm trying to get XML parsing down (and yes I know there's easier ways to parse/validate like xstream) but I can't seem to get text content of just a single element. For example:

```
<container>
   <element0>textThatIWant</element0> //only returned by .getTextContent
   <element1>
      <subelement0>textThatIDontWant</subelement0> //but also returned by
      <subelement1>textThatIDontWant</subelement1> //.getTextContent
   </element1>
<container>
```

I'm piping results out to the console and get mostly what I'm looking for but the only way I seem to get the text strings is with `.getTextContent()` which returns all text in the sub elements, as well, without whitespace (or else I'd have split on spaces) or `.getNodeValue().toString()` which throws `nullPointerExceptions`. @Jihar mentioned something like `.getTextValue()` but Eclipse doesn't recognize it (maybe there's something I can implement/inherit/whatever to add capability), any help?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws  ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      String appendage = "..." //This string holds the xml formatted data I'll be 
                               //using in a long annoying line, I'll include it 
                               //separately for clarity
      xmlStringBuilder.append(appendage);   
      ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

      System.out.println("Test Results:");
      System.out.println();

      Document doc = builder.parse(input);
      Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
      NodeList children = root.getChildNodes();

      System.out.println(root.getTagName());
      System.out.println();

      for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
         Node child = children.item(i);
         if (child instanceof Element) { 
            Element childElement = (Element) child; 
            System.out.println(childElement.getTagName() + " " + childElement);

            NodeList grandChildren = child.getChildNodes();
            for (int x = 0; x < grandChildren.getLength(); x++) {
               Node grandChild = grandChildren.item(x);
               if (grandChild instanceof Element) {
                  Element grandChildElement = (Element) grandChild;
                  System.out.print("\t" + grandChildElement.getTagName() + ":\t");

                  NodeList greatGrandChildren = grandChild.getChildNodes();
                  for (int y = 0; y < greatGrandChildren.getLength(); y++) {
                     Node greatGrandChild = greatGrandChildren.item(y);
                     if (greatGrandChild instanceof Element) {
                        Element greatGrandChildElement = (Element) greatGrandChild;
                        System.out.print(" " + greatGrandChildElement.getTextContent());
                        if ( y < greatGrandChildren.getLength() - 1) { System.out.print(","); } }
                     }
                     System.out.println();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And here's the appendage variable in full:

```
String appendage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><branch0><name>business</name><taxINFO/><personnel><executives><name>Billy Bob</name><name>Colonel Jessup</name></executives><managerial/><operations><name>sabrina</name><name>lisa</name></operations><services><name>jamie</name><name>justin</name><name>forest</name></services></personnel><regions><ebay><area>OK</area><area>BE</area><area>EV</area><area>WC</area></ebay><sbay><area>SJ</area><area>MP</area><area>SV</area><area>MV</area></sbay><S.F.><area>SF</area></S.F.><N.Y.><area>NY</area></N.Y.><S.CA><area>SD</area><area>LA</area></S.CA></regions><products/><services/></branch0>";
```

or:

```
String appendage = "
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<branch0>
   <name>business</name>
   <taxINFO/>
   <personnel>
      <executives>
         <name>Billy Bob</name>
         <name>Colonel Jessup</name>
      </executives>
   <managerial/>
   <operations>
      <name>sabrina</name>
      <name>lisa</name>
   </operations>
   <services>
      <name>jamie</name>
      <name>justin</name>
      <name>forest</name>
   </services>
   </personnel>
   <regions>
      <ebay>
         <area>OK</area>
         <area>BE</area>
         <area>EV</area>
         <area>WC</area>
      </ebay>
      <sbay>
         <area>SJ</area>
         <area>MP</area>
         <area>SV</area>
         <area>MV</area>
      </sbay>
      <S.F.>
         <area>SF</area>
      </S.F.>
      <N.Y.>
         <area>NY</area>
      </N.Y.>
      <S.CA>
         <area>SD</area>
         <area>LA</area>
      </S.CA>
   </regions>
   <products/>
   <services/>
</branch0>";
";
```

And, finally my console output (which you'll see is stating `[name: null]` where I'd like it to say something like `[name: business]` or even just `business`; but not include the sub element data w/out whitespace):

```
Test Results:

branch0

name [name: null]
taxINFO [taxINFO: null]
personnel [personnel: null]
    executives:  Billy Bob, Colonel Jessup
    managerial: 
    operations:  sabrina, lisa
    services:    jamie, justin, forest
regions [regions: null]
    ebay:    OK, BE, EV, WC
    sbay:    SJ, MP, SV, MV
    S.F.:    SF
    N.Y.:    NY
    S.CA:    SD, LA
products [products: null]
services [services: null]
```

and here's my console output using `.getTextContent`:

```
Test Results:
business
branch0

name business
taxINFO 
personnel Billy BobColonel Jessupsabrinalisajamiejustinforest
 executives:     Billy Bob, Colonel Jessup
 managerial:    
 operations:     sabrina, lisa
 services:   jamie, justin, forest
regions OKBEEVWCSJMPSVMVSFNYSDLA
 ebay:   OK, BE, EV, WC
 sbay:   SJ, MP, SV, MV
 S.F.:   SF
 N.Y.:   NY
 S.CA:   SD, LA
products 
services
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(childElement.getTagName() + " " + childElement);
```

should be (as you actually know!)

```
System.out.println(childElement.getTagName() + " "
    + childElement.getTextContent());
```

Comment: This is my console results using that: `personnel Billy BobColonel Jessupsabrinalisajamiejustinforest
 executives:  Billy Bob, Colonel Jessup
 managerial: 
 operations:  sabrina, lisa
 services:  jamie, justin, forest
regions OKBEEVWCSJMPSVMVSFNYSDLA
 ebay:  OK, BE, EV, WC
 sbay:  SJ, MP, SV, MV
 S.F.:  SF
 N.Y.:  NY
 S.CA:  SD, LA`

Comment: The formatting comes out weird in comments, but basically that works only when there are no sub elements.

Comment: I can isolate to just the text I need with .getNodeValue().toString but I've been having trouble testing for null condition (NodeValue seems to be 'null' even when text is present, which makes me think I'm missing something about the referencing of element's data?), so whitespace kicks a nullPointerException <argh!>

Comment: The "node value" of an element node is always null by definition. If you want the text inside the element but not the text inside its child elements then you'll have to iterate over the element's list of child nodes and process just those children that are text nodes, not element nodes.

Comment: I'm confused, why does .getNodeValue().toString() return the text inside the element tags if NodeValue is null by definition? I was getting code returned (hex chars I think) and used .toString() to format that into the proper response. Is the nodeValue supposed to be referring to the tag name itself? Also, could you include an answer explaining how you iterate over the child nodes? I'm still figuring this stuff out...

Answer (score 0):

So, for my purposes, I was able to get the individual elements I was looking for using an XPath:

```
XPathFactory xpfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath path = xpfactory.newXPath();
try {
    String aString = path.evaluate("/branch0/name", doc);
    System.out.println(aString);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Of course this requires pre-existing knowledge of the structure, but since I can validate with an XML Schema and my docs are not too complicated/heavily nested I don't think that will be an issue for me. When I finish working on my current project I'll try to look up and post links about iterating over the child nodes and checking for text nodes (as @Ian Roberts suggested) but I don't know enough about XML to do that now.